# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()"
I got this exception and i don't know how to deal with it I'm a beginner so please I'm asking for you help!

Comment: You got another exception when you tried to get the `Connection` and you ignored that. Don't. You don't actually have a `Connection`.

Comment: As asked, this question is a duplicate. If you want more specific help, then please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: thank you everyone  so muchh, i just fixed it